# Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null - Tiny Slider React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spfx

React newbie here, I am having problems with my TinySlider component. Each time I update in the UI how many posts can appear in the carousel, I get this error every other update which I need to fix:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

If I remove `<TinySlider settings={...settings}></Tinyslider>` I do not get this error.

I have tried this: `{ renderProfilesCarousel ? renderProfilesCarousel : '' }` inside the `<tinySlider>` but that does not work.

Any idea what I could do here? Pretty stuck on this now.

```
// React
import * as React from 'react';
// Styling
import styles from './LinkedIn.module.scss';
// Importing the props
import { ILinkedInProps } from './ILinkedInProps';
// Importing the state
import { ILinkedInState } from './ILinkedInState';
// Removes special characters 
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
// Library for making http requests
import axios from 'axios';
// Library for creating unique ids
import shortid from 'shortid';
// Fabric UI elements
import {
  DocumentCard,
  DocumentCardPreview,
  DocumentCardType,
  DocumentCardDetails,
  DocumentCardTitle,
  IDocumentCardPreviewProps
} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DocumentCard';
import { ImageFit, Image } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Image';
// Sort array
import sortBy from 'sort-array';
import TinySlider from "tiny-slider-react";
import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';
import "./styles.scss";

// LinkedIn Component Class
export default class LinkedIn extends React.Component<ILinkedInProps, ILinkedInState> {

  // State needed for the component
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        profiles: [],
        isLoading: true,
        errors: null
    };
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.2/tiny-slider.css');
  }

  // This function runs when component is first renderd
  public componentDidMount() {
    this.getProfiles();
  }

  // This function runs when props that have changed have been passed in
  public componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if ( prevProps.listName !== this.props.listName || prevProps.postCount ! == this.props.postCount )
    {
      this.renderProfile();
    }
  }

  // Grabs LinkedIn profiles - This service runs once a day
  private getProfiles() {
    let companyNameCreate: string;
    let backUpImageCreate: string;
    axios
      .get(
        "https://cors-anywhere-spfx.herokuapp.com/" +
        "https://cache1.phantombooster.com/YRrbtT9qhg0/KJhwG7zo0zPE5zc9Eehn6Q/result.json"
      )
      .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        profiles: response.data.filter(d => d.postContent).map(post => {
          if (post.profileUrl == 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/')
          {
            companyNameCreate = 'company';
            backUpImageCreate = 'https://media-exp2.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D0BAQEbfV4VNvsJyg/company-logo_100_100/0?e=1587600000&v=beta&t=CX_s-ekYNn0TnXANeftQkLZ9jIvMW7PtDTLLcHcu9wY'
          }
          else if (post.profileUrl == 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/1')
          {
            companyNameCreate = 'company';
            backUpImageCreate = 'https://media-exp2.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D0BAQG_Pr1cDaGfdA/company-logo_200_200/0?e=1587600000&v=beta&t=C0fWkjbO2Elth8K4pG4i_kzwlu8dvQvN1Ws-yKGxxP4'
          }
          else if (post.profileUrl == 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/2')
          {
            companyNameCreate = 'company';
            backUpImageCreate = 'https://media-exp2.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D0BAQHdub-mnNwSNg/company-logo_100_100/0?e=1587600000&v=beta&t=druqo_O5gB5cExttREUlSdGnJhr4Wx2-PCjshJ0K0fI'
          }
          else if (post.profileUrl == 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/3')
          {
            companyNameCreate = 'company';
            backUpImageCreate = 'https://media-exp2.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D0BAQEUKGn5i1EnQA/company-logo_100_100/0?e=1587600000&v=beta&t=uwE3CUaodiqmW2K3a3Hm57QDIDlMvrmfmoHDvlGnzuY'
          }
          else if (post.profileUrl =='https://www.linkedin.com/company/4')
          {
            companyNameCreate = 'company';
            backUpImageCreate = 'https://media-exp2.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D0BAQGYqqxF43Rfdg/company-logo_200_200/0?e=1587600000&v=beta&t=4hmLzdbkjk_hL3rwonWgTbUF1V-itkyBEfLBh85G7_k'
          }
          else if (post.profileUrl == 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/5')
          {
            companyNameCreate = 'company';
            backUpImageCreate = 'https://media-exp2.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E0BAQHsNKLawvW7zg/company-logo_100_100/0?e=1587600000&v=beta&t=26Otro4T3q90GznPxXX6n3oPTYYWIgzodOIask0enu4'
          }
          return {
            ...post,
            companyName: companyNameCreate,
            backUpImage:  backUpImageCreate
          }
        })
      });
    })
    // Error catching
    .catch(errors => this.setState({ errors, isLoading: false }));
  }

  // Creates the renderd layout of the LinkedIn profile
  private async renderProfile() {
    let filter: string = '';
    // Works out which profile to display
    switch (this.props.listName) {
      case "abfi":
        filter = 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/1';
        break;
      case 'abEnzymes':
        filter = 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/2';
        break;
      case 'abitec':
        filter = 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/3';
        break;
      case 'ohly':
        filter = 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/4';
        break; 
      case 'pgpi':
        filter = 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/5';
        break;
      case 'spiPharma':
        filter = 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/6';
        break;
      case 'all': 
        filter = 'Post';
        break;
      default:
        filter = 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/1';
        return filter;
    }

    // Grabs the array of objects
    let { profiles } = this.state;

    const slotOrder = [
      "", "1h","2h","3h","4h","5h","6h","7h","8h","9h","10h","11h","12h", "13h","14h","15h","16h","17h","18h","19h","20h","21h","22h", "23h", "2d", "3d", "4d", "5d", "6d", "1w", "2w", "3w", "1mo", "2mo", "3mo", "4mo", "5mo", "6mo", "7mo", "8mo", "9mo", "10mo", "11mo", "1yr", "2yr"
    ];

    // Select only the needed objects from the array
    let selectedProfile;

    // Display all posts 
    if (this.props.listName !== 'all') {
      selectedProfile = profiles.filter(profile => profile.profileUrl == filter);
    } else {
      selectedProfile = profiles.filter(profile => profile.action == filter);
    }

    selectedProfile = sortBy(selectedProfile, "postDate", { postDate: slotOrder })
    selectedProfile = selectedProfile.splice(0, this.props.postCount)

    // Renders the selected profile
    let renderProfilesCarousel = selectedProfile.map(profile => {

      // If LinkedIn post has no image, then add a fallback!
      if (profile.imgUrl == "" || profile.imgUrl == null ) {
        profile.imgUrl = profile.backUpImage;
      }

      // Removes hashtag line from posts
      profile.postContent = profile.postContent.replace(/hashtag/g, '');

      return(
        <div className={styles.linkedInContainerCarousel} style={{ position: "relative" }} key={shortid.generate()}>
          <a href={profile.postUrl} target="_blank" data-interception="off"> 
              <DocumentCard
                aria-label={profile.postContent}
                className={styles.linkedInDocCard}
              > 
                { profile.imgUrl && 
                  <Image
                    src={profile.imgUrl}
                    imageFit={ImageFit.cover}
                    height={168}
                  />
                }
                <DocumentCardTitle
                  title={profile.postContent}
                  shouldTruncate={true}
                />
                <p className={ styles.linkedInCompany}>{profile.companyName}</p>
                <p className={ styles.linkedInLikes}>{`Likes: ${profile.likeCount}`}</p>
              </DocumentCard>
          </a>
        </div>
      )
    });

    // Renders the selected profile
    let renderProfiles = selectedProfile.map(profile => {

      // If LinkedIn post has no image, then add a fallback!
      if (profile.imgUrl == "" || profile.imgUrl == null ) {
        profile.imgUrl = profile.backUpImage;
      }

      let previewProps: IDocumentCardPreviewProps = {
        previewImages: [
          {
            name: profile.postContent,
            previewImageSrc: profile.imgUrl,
            iconSrc: null,
            imageFit: ImageFit.cover,
            height: 110,
            width: 110
          }
        ]
      };

      return(
        <div className={styles.linkedInContainer} style={{ position: "relative" }} key={shortid.generate()}>
          <a href={profile.postUrl} target="_blank" data-interception="off"> 
              <DocumentCard
                aria-label={profile.postContent}
                className={styles.linkedInDocCard}
                type={DocumentCardType.compact}
              > 
                { profile.imgUrl && 
                  <DocumentCardPreview {...previewProps} />
                }
                <DocumentCardDetails>
                <DocumentCardTitle
                  title={profile.postContent}
                  shouldTruncate={true}
                />
                  <p className={ styles.linkedInCompany}>{profile.companyName}</p>
                  <p className={ styles.linkedInLikes}>{`Likes: ${profile.likeCount}`}</p>
                </DocumentCardDetails>
              </DocumentCard>
          </a>
        </div>
      )
    });

    let settings: any;

    if (this.props.toggleInfoHeaderValue == true )
    {
      settings = {
        lazyload: true,
        nav: false,
        mouseDrag: false,
        items: 1,
        swipeAngle: false,
        speed: 400,
        autoplay: false,
        axis: "horizontal",
        autoHeight: false,
        rewind: true,
        fixedWidth: false
      };
    }
    else
    {
      settings = {
        lazyload: true,
        nav: false,
        mouseDrag: false,
        items: 3,
        swipeAngle: false,
        speed: 400,
        autoplay: false,
        axis: "vertical",
        autoHeight: false,
        rewind: true,
        fixedWidth: false
      };
    };

    if (this.props.toggleInfoScrollValue) {
      settings.autoplay = true;
    } else {
      settings.autoplay = false;
    }

    if (this.props.toggleInfoHeaderValue == true ) {
      return(
        <div>
            <TinySlider settings={settings}>
               {renderProfilesCarousel}
            </TinySlider>
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (

        <div className={styles.upArrows}>
            <TinySlider settings={settings}>
               {renderProfiles}
            </TinySlider>
        </div>
      )
    }   

  } 

  // Renders to the browser
  public render(): React.ReactElement<ILinkedInProps> {

    return (
      <div className={ styles.linkedIn }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <p className={ styles.title }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
          <div>
            { this.renderProfile() }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Error in full:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counld you try this instead

```
{ renderProfilesCarousel ? renderProfilesCarousel : <span></span> }
```

React likes it when it has [elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html), and I'm not sure how it'd deal with a ''

Edit to edit:

I think you'll want to move the actual JSX.Element out of the renderProfile() method. React doesn't take that as a child element.

So I added two new items to state (I guess you'll want three, one for renderProfilesCarousel too):

```
settings?: any;
renderProfiles?: JSX.Element[];
```

Then I did this at the bottom of the renderProfile() method:

```
        /* if (this.props.toggleInfoHeaderValue == true) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <TinySlider settings={settings}>
                        {renderProfilesCarousel}
                    </TinySlider>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return (

                <div /* className={styles.upArrows} >
                    <TinySlider settings={settings}>
                        {renderProfiles}
                    </TinySlider>
                </div>
            )
        } */
        console.log(renderProfiles.length);
        this.setState({
            settings: settings,
            renderProfiles: renderProfiles,
            isLoading: false
        })
```

Then, in your return of the actual render to the browser is where I put the actual JSX.Element:

```
    // Renders to the browser
    public render(): React.ReactElement<ILinkedInProfilesProps> {
        const {settings, renderProfiles} = this.state;
        const theRenderProfileJsxElement: JSX.Element = 
            <div /* className={styles.upArrows} */>
                <TinySlider settings={settings}>
                    {renderProfiles}
                </TinySlider>
            </div>;
        return (
            <div /* className={styles.linkedIn} */>
                <div /* className={styles.container} */>
                    <p /* className={styles.title} */>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
                    <div>
                        {this.state.isLoading === false &&
                            theRenderProfileJsxElement
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

And I used your state of isLoading to prevent the Carousel from loading prior to finishing all the logic and loading from above.

Also! If you don't have React Dev Tools on your browser, you need it!

[image]

I can see the component Carousel, but I didn't do the if logic for either the toggleInfoHeaderValue. Let's see if that works?

Comment: Give it a go, but no Luck :(

Comment: Are you still stuck? What's this?  { this.renderProfile() }

Comment: Yeah still stuck, I can't get a demo over you either as its built within the SPFX framework :(

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the method renderProfile() and it's location in the React.Component class? Is renderProfile a JSX.Element? Is it valid? That's where I'm going with this? :) Tracing the children of the component.

Comment: Its all in there now!

Comment: Ok, I edited my earlier answer because I got it wrong :) Lemme know if that gets you a JSX.Element. I think I may have actually removed one other thing of note, that you've got to move the switch statement out, because you don't want to return just the filter string. I have that commented out. `filter = 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/1';
    //return filter;`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write that code out, you have tackled the problem better then me but I have learnt from your code :) Sadly I am still getting the orginal error lol I think I will remove TinySlider and try a didderent one. I have uploaded a full image of the errors.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I had also commented out your componentDidUpdate(); I should have kept track of the changes I made. Here's a [gist of it](https://gist.github.com/jcrocke9/428ab977f79943cb56bae3faae104de0). I do think it's a React issue, not a TinySlider issue, I haven't had any issues with it before.